# Advanced search form with checkboxes

Tags: categories, search, queries, checkboxes

So it seems that [Matrix fields don't work with the object syntax](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13099/advanced-filtered-search-matrix-fields-and-arrays) so I've changed my field structure to use standard dropdowns, checkboxes and a number field.

I have the dropdown (`gender`) and number field (`maxPrice`) working fine, but I can't seem to figure out what to enter for the checkboxes. I assumed it'd be in a similar format to what I've seen elsewhere, as you can see below:

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

{% set tags = craft.request.getParam('tags') %}

{# Gender is a dropdown, so it's a single value or no value
 # - If an empty value is selected, it returns both genders #}
{% set gender = craft.request.getParam('gender') %}

{% set maxPrice = craft.request.getParam('maxPrice') %}
{% set maxPrice = maxPrice is not empty ? maxPrice : '99' %}

{% set sessions = craft.request.getParam('sessions') %}
{% set sessions = sessions is not empty ? sessions : ['skype', 'chat', 'phone', 'email'] %}
{% set sessions = ['and']|merge(sessions) %}

{% set hours = craft.request.getParam('hours') %}
{% set hours = hours is not empty ? hours : ['office', 'overtime', 'weekends'] %}
{% set hours = ['and']|merge(hours) %}

{% set results = craft.users({
  group: 'verified',
  search: "tagsSpecialismSearchable:#{tags}",
  gender: gender,
  profilePricingSession: [
    'and',
    '> 0',
    "<= #{maxPrice}"
  ],
  profileSessions: sessions,
  profileHours: hours,
}) %}

{% set users = shuffle(results) %}
```

Everything works except `profileSessions` and `profileHours`, which are both checkboxes. I assumed it might be that they need to be passed a `key: value` pair, i.e: `skype: true` or some other method, but nothing I've tried so far is working.

I happened on a post saying [checkboxes store in a query unfriendly way](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13190/search-against-a-checkboxes-fields-options), so perhaps I'm better off changing the field again for something more friendly. They'd need to be multi-select of course, so categories would be the best bet if what I'm doing isn't possible.

Suggestions?

Comment: @carlcs Not quite, but if the sentiments are the same: i.e. checkboxes aren't searchable in this way, I guess I'll have to go with categories. If possible, could you point me in the direction of a post that uses categories with the object syntax in a similar way? Would I use `relatedTo`? (it still confuses me a bit, especially when using [`field`, `sourceElement` and `targetElement`](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param))

Comment: How many checkboxes / categories do you have, @Rob? Have you considered using lightswitches?

Comment: Here's an example for a dynamic `relatedTo` parameter: [Dynamic relatedTo queries](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/11870/125) (categories are most likely to be the `targetElement`, as they are the elements selected in the field and not the element the field is attachted to).

Comment: @carlcs Yeah that's the thing, I only have about 8 in total which seems overkill to use categories, but lightswitches might look a bit fuggly on the backend (the users can edit their profile in the CP). Is that a similar method to `dropdown: 'value'` or would it be something like `field: true` or `field: '0'`? Craft is brilliant but these little intricacies can take some getting used to — hopefully the v3 api will give us more options :)

Comment: I have written a checkbox fieldtype (note the singular) for a project, which stores the data like a lightswitch field, but looks like the checkboxes field in the CP. I'll push it to GitHub for you, so you can keep the looks in the CP, but store in a query friendly way. ;-)

Comment: @carlcs Sounds great! Be good to see how you manage it .. Is it future compatable? So many ways to build a thing on Craft :)

Comment: Just released it: https://github.com/carlcs/craft-checkboxfield

Comment: @carlcs Perfect, looks like it'll come in handy ... thanks!

Comment: @carlcs I'm struggling to get your [Dynamic relatedTo query](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11870/dynamic-relatedto-queries) example working, if using for multi-selectable categories in 2 category groups. I think [this example](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9081/how-to-filter-entries-by-clicking-multiple-categories-on-front-end/9083#9083) is closer to what I'm looking for. Am I right in thinking the only way to do this is adding a `for loop` through all the `query[]=` group arrays? I don't think I fully understand what your example is doing.

Comment: FYI I'm using slugs as values for the checkboxes. I assumed at first what you were doing is passing `query.art` parameter array into `.id()` and merging each with it's own `{ targetElement: categoryName }`, but I thought `.id()` and `.slug` could only take one string at a time. Is it something similar to the [second example in Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) which (due to being wrapped in `[]` creates a list of `key: value` pairs? Or am I off the mark? I come from a front-end background so this stuff makes my head hurt!

Comment: @badlydrawnrob on Slack ... I almost have it figured out thanks to [Twig dump](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) but the search results are doing some funky things.