# Using search criteria in modifyEntrySources plugin

Tags: plugin-development, search, sources

I have articles with a multi-select named `theme`.

This works fine in a template:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('article').search('theme:themeFoobar') %}
<p>{{ entries | length }}</p>
```

I'm working on a plugin to create a custom source containing only those articles that have `themeFoobar` selected in their multi-select, this is what I have:

```
public function modifyEntrySources(&$sources, $context)
{
  $sources[] = array('heading' => 'Themes');

  $sources['theme:foobar'] = array(
    'label' => 'Theme: Foobar',
    'criteria' => array(
      'section' => 'article',
      'search' => 'theme:themeFoobar'
    )
  );
}
```

The result of this is that the source contains all articles, it looks like the `search` criteria is completely ignored.

Is `search` not the correct criteria to use here? Is there another criteria I can use to find only the articles with `themeFoobar` selected in the multi-select?

### Further information

The multi-select used to be just a dropdown. When it was a dropdown, this plugin worked fine:

```
public function modifyEntrySources(&$sources, $context)
{
  $sources[] = array('heading' => 'Themes');

  $sources['theme:foobar'] = array(
    'label' => 'Theme: Foobar',
    'criteria' => array(
      'section' => 'article',
      'theme' => 'themeFoobar'
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change it to `'search' => 'theme:*themeFoobar*'`? The multi select stores the array of values as a JSON string to the database.

Comment: @carlcs nope, same result. All articles are returned, the search criteria appears to have no effect.

Comment: Hey @esseb, the solutions I posted to this question should also work from PHP. [Search against a checkboxes field's options](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/13190/125)

Comment: @carlcs If you'd like, go ahead and write that as an answer and I'll accept it. I'll post my own final code later once I clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution, thanks to @carlcs:

```
public function modifyEntrySources(&$sources, $context)
{
    $sources[] = array('heading' => Craft::t('Themes'));

    $themes = array(
        'THEME_FOO' => 'themeFoo',
        'THEME_BAR' => 'themeBar'
    );

    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'article';
    $articles = $criteria->find();

    foreach ($themes as $theme => $label)
    {
        // Loop through all articles and check if they contain the current theme.
        // If they do, add it to the ids array which we will later use to filter
        // just the articles with this theme.
        $ids = [];
        foreach ($articles as $article)
        {
            foreach ($article->theme as $articleTheme)
            {
                if ($articleTheme == $themes[$theme])
                {
                    array_push($ids, $article->id);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $sources['theme:' . $label] = array(
            'label' => Craft::t('Theme') . ': ' . Craft::t($theme),
            'criteria' => array(
                'section' => 'article',
                'id' => $ids
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The PHP itself could be cleaned up, but this works for now.

Categories would probably have been a simpler solution had I gone for that originally.